# java.text.DecimalFormat equivalent in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, decimalformat

In java, I have

```
String snumber = null;
String mask = "000000000000";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
snumber = df.format(number);  //'number' is of type 'long' passed to a function
                              //which has this code in it
```

I am not aware of the `DecimalFormat` operations in java and so finding it hard to write an equivalent Obj C code.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular case you can use some C-style magic inside Objective-C:

```
long number = 123;
int desiredLength = 10;

NSString *format  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%0%dd", desiredLength];
NSString *snumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, number];
```

Result is `0000000123`.
Format here will be `%010d`.
`10d` means that you'll have 10 spots for number aligned to right.
`0` at the beginning causes that all "empty" spots will be filled with 0.
If number is shorter than desiredLength, it is formatted just as it is (without leading zeros).
Of course, above code is valid only when you want to have numbers with specified length with gaps filled by zeros.
For other scenarios you could e.g. write own custom class which would use appropriate printf/NSLog formats to produce strings formatted as you wish.
In Objective-C, instead of using DecimalFormat "masks", you have to live with string formats.